# Is there any possibility classify type of key in redis?

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

I have a question if redis is doing classify key type. For example, `SET 123 1` and `SET 123abc 1` are different keys absolutely. but I'm wondering if the types of keys are different, `123` is a integer type, and `123abc` is string type. I guess, there is any problem in redis-driver libraries, for example node-redis. I delete key by `123` string type of javascript, but this may be not completed, because they are different types, integer type in redis and string type in node.js.

Is this a shit idea? I have some issues made this idea. please let me know facts. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Key names are always strings.

> I delete key by 123 string type of javascript, but this may be not completed, because they are different types, integer type in redis and string type in node.js.

No, this is not what happens. The error is elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer like a flash. have a nice day.